# What is the reason for U&L questions appearing in AU chat?

Tags: discussion

Is there any reason why U&L site questions with "ubuntu" tag appear in AU chat?

Comment: It's done by the official StackExchange bot [Ubuntu Questions on U&L](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-45/ubuntu-questions-on-ul) (negative user-ID `-45` means that it belongs to the system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is the Ubuntu site.

While they're on topic there, some questions are better suited to us, and would be good migration targets, or a user from here might be able to answer it.

Essentially, it shows the question to a wider audience.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: nice =)..why only from U&L

Comment: @Ravan not sure. Maybe we should have it from server fault too? http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu

Comment: I am also not sure that only from U&L but I observed majority of times from U&L :)

Comment: Too many feeds will just make the whole thing just noise. And I think we share more userbase with U&L.